# mysql and date comparison with date function and without

Tags: mysql

I notice a strange behavior for me when using `date()` and without:

when I use

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE date(date_add) >= '2017-08-01' and date(date_add) <= '2017-08-31'
```

I get all dates records within the given date range but if do:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE date_add >= '2017-08-01' and date_add <= '2017-08-31'
```

I don't get the rows from the last day 31, why? (the date_add field is datetime type)

**EDIT:**

How should I code date range correctly? Because what I understand so far is that if I don't use full time like `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS` I should always compare with `DATE()` to avoid missing results from the last day.

Comment: Can you also add the type of date_add column in the post?

Answer (score 0):

That's because `date_add` is a `DATETIME` field. If the time for the date `2017-08-31` is something like `08:15:00` or `13:21:00` in your table, your date is "bigger" than just `2017-08-31 00:00:00`. Your comparison would just return data for the `2017-08-31` having the time `00:00:00`.

Comment: I've edited my post, I wounder what is the best practice when giving date range in where condition? Because when I have more complicated query I get strange results.

Answer (score 0):

Because without the `date()` transformation your comparison imply the values `'2017-08-01 00:00:00' and '2017-08-01 00:00:00'`